# What makes a function aysnc or sync in swift?

Tags: swift, asynchronous

I saw `URLSession.dataTask(with:completionHandler:)` is **async** function, and `Data(contentsOf:)` is **sync** function. What make these function are **async** or **sync**?

Comment: Asynchronous methods generally provide mechanism to inform caller when the call is done. They generally have a "completion handler" closure parameter or their class has a "delegate" property. So, if you see either of these, it's a red flag, indicating that it's possibly asynchronous. This is not a hard and fast rule (e.g. we *could* write an asynchonous method that does not provide any mechanism to inform the caller of completion), but that's a pretty poor design and is pretty rare. And there are definitely closure/delegate patterns that are not asynchronous. Always confirm via documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Methods / method calls are always sync. But some methods *behave* in an async way meaning that even after the method completes / returns there is still work being done.

There is nothing in the definition of a method that states wether or not it behaves that way. The fact that there is a completionHandler *hints* that the method is probably doing some async work but it is no guarantee and the absence of a completionHandler neither guarantees that the method does not do some async work. *If* a methods accepts a completion handler and does some async work and the completionHandler would be called after the method returns then there has to be a `@escaping` on the closure parameter.

---

Bottom line: you have to read the docs and / or look at the implementation of the method to understand what it does.

Comment: Building on what @luk2302 said: In order to control your own methods to do sync or async stuff, you can put them on a DispatchQueue, on which you can specifically call .sync{ ... }, .async { ... } respectively. For more detailed information about that, refer to the Apple documentation about GCD: 
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/OperationQueues/OperationQueues.html